# jquery hover state after opacity

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

once i click the button the image opacity changes but still the re button appears on hover
is it possible to remove the red button completely once the opacity of the image changes...

http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/11/

providing my js code below

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                  $(".specialHoverOne").hover(function(){
    //  alert("i am here");
                    $(".ctaSpecialOne").css("visibility","visible");


                    },
                    function(){
                        $(".ctaSpecialOne").css("visibility","hidden");
                  }
                  );

     $(".ctaSpecialOne").click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();

                        $(this).parent().prev().prev().css({'opacity':.5});    

                 }); 


                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...assuming that .ctaSpecialOne is the class for the red button...

```
$(".ctaSpecialOne").on('click', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Integrated into your code

```
 $(".ctaSpecialOne").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().prev().prev().css({'opacity':.5});
     $(this).remove();   
 });
```

Comment: he asked for after the opacity change, that would just do it strait away... so the opacity would not have any effect whats so ever and is redundant...

Comment: The opacity effects the Magazine element...and when the button is clicked, it changes the opacity of the magazine and removes the button.  Simple enough.

Comment: Haha, thanks...I was really hoping not to get into a 'comment' battle first thing in the morning x)

Comment: @VIDesignz: thanks for your reply is it possible to obtain this kind of opacity https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3IBJKENGE7RS1lwZzhYbTNRbkk/edit?pli=1 http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/18/ your code works

Comment: @user1828505 You mean with the Logo in the middle?

Comment: @user1828505 I would add a div with the logo and close/cancel button for each magazine and set display:none; then call display:block in the same function that changes the magazine opacity :)

Comment: @VIDesignz: do you know how to add the images in js fiddle show that i can show u

Comment: @user1828506 I can surely try!

Comment: @user1828506 Sorry man, at work right now... do you have a link to the logo?

Comment: @VIDesignz: here is the image link http://imgs.zinio.com/www/images/checkout/X.png

Comment: @user1828506 Cool, how about the zpass logo?

Comment: @VIDesignz: i tried here its not working http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/22/      <div id="opacityCross">

Comment: @user1828506 Me too man...there is too much going on in the javascript at the bottom, and in the css for me to isolate what we need to do...I assume that is not all your script? Maybe if you can take out all the extra stuff and just leave the script and css styling that is applicable to your page, I can help you out.

Comment: @VIDesignz: can u some how help me out

Comment: @user1828505 I wish I could man...I messed with it yesterday for a while and I just cant get the positioning correct, and it keeps changing the dimension of the x button to the same size as the magazine image.

Comment: @user1828505 I see you made some progress on it though, nice work!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().prev().prev().css({'opacity':.5}).stop(true,true).delay(1).queue(function (){
    ... your code here ...
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

This is how I normally approach it...

I would also recommend changing the `.css` to `.animate` then you can do the following...

```
$(this).parent().prev().prev().stop(true,true).animate({'opacity':.5}).delay(1).queue(function (){
    ... your code here ...
    $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply is it possible for you to show it in the fiddle i tried it its not working http://jsfiddle.net/mwPeb/19/